# sum each price with previous value as a new value in react js

Tags: arrays, object, sum, reduce

I have an array of object and I want sum each price value with last price as a new value this is my data  with final data I

```js
data=[{price: 2, volume: 123}
{price: 3, volume: 123}
{price: 4, volume: 254}
{price: 1, volume: 444}
{price: 5, volume: 555}]

finalfata=[{price: 2, volume: 555}
1: {price: 5, volume: 777}
2: {price: 9, volume: 5000}
3: {price: 10, volume: 8000}
4: {price: 15, volume: 4000}]
```

except

Answer (score 0):

You can use [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to sum the prices as grouped by each volume:

```js
const data = [ 
{price: 2, volume: 123},
{price: 3, volume: 123},
{price: 4, volume: 254},
{price: 1, volume: 444},
{price: 5, volume: 555}
];

const finalData = data.reduce((tot, each) => 
  [...tot, { ...each, price: each.price + (tot.at(-1) || { price: 0 }).price }]
, []);

console.log(finalData);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let prevPrice = 0
let prevVolume = 0
data.forEach(d => { prevPrice += d.price; prevVolume += d.volume; 
    d.price = prevPrice; 
    d.volume = prevVolume;
    return d;
})
```